# Facebook Ads Scheduler in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, facebook-ads-api

![1]: http://www.socialmediaexaminer.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/fr-image-7.jpg "Facebook ads scheduler"

I want to develop a similar tool to one of our application, suggest appropriate wpf tools needs to be used. Is there any wpf project already exists on it?

Reagrds.

Answer (score 0):

There is no C# or .Net Ads SDKs from Facebook.  But there are options on the internet.  You can use them to make Graph API calls to Facebook server.

You may refer to the following page to understand how to use APIs to control ads schedule.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/pacing